# FrameLayout - adding content to FrameLayout to display properly

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I'm using `FrameLayout` cause for some reason when I add `fragments` to my main layout the new `fragment` needs to be a `FrameLayout` to get the proper `match_parent` height.

But now I am facing an issue with laying out the content of the `FrameLayout`. It is complaining because I am using a `LinearLayout` inside a `FrameLayout`.

How do you layout content in a `FrameLayout`?

```
<FrameLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lhf"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Logo"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:rotation="0"
            android:scaleX="0.0"
            android:scaleY="0.0"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:x="150dp"
            android:y="150dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtWelcome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**UPDATED**

I get the following warning

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - This LinearLayout layout or its FrameLayout parent is useless
    - This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is the problem exactly here? (I pasted it in Eclipse and got no errors)

Comment: I've updated the question, show the warning I am getting

Comment: @K3NN3TH : it is not an `error` it is a `lint warning`

Comment: @kaushik so nothing to worry about?

Comment: @K3NN3TH : you can `optimize` your `layout` to remove those extra `views`

Comment: @kaushik not sure what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an `error` it is a `lint warning`. You can replace the `ImageView` using `compound drawable` of that `TextView` and no need of that `LinearLayout`.

You can set drawable on that `TextView` using `one of these` attributes.

```
android:drawableLeft
android:drawableTop
android:drawableRight
android:drawableBottom
```

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29